# how can I set postgres exporter query interval

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-postgres-exporter

Im using postgres exporter - https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter/
I  increased the scrape interval in servicemonitor in my k8s deploy but it looks like queries.yml is stil running every 15 sec is there any other things I should change beside k8s side?

Comment: I am not familiar with prometheus-operator, so sorry if it is out of place. Have you checked `/config` endpoint at your prometheus (to see final compiled configuration of scraping)? Could it be that change of scraping config is applied to some other job?

Comment: Check the logs of postgres exporter pod and from that logs you will be able to know whether there are any errors or any underlying reasons for your **`queries.yml`** file to execute even though you have changed the **scrape interval**.